# Problem configuring touchscreen for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

I want to use this [3.5" adafruit touchscreen](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2050), so I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/easy-install)

I ran the following commands from the link :

```
curl -SLs https://apt.adafruit.com/add | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-bootloader
sudo apt-get install adafruit-pitft-helper
sudo adafruit-pitft-helper -t 28r
```

When rebooting I get just a part of the touchscreen that is displaying Raspbian and I want it fullscreen.

I don't know firstly that I need a tutorial for 3.5 inch and not 2.8 inch so what I did I ran this command again with a little change because I'm using 3.5 inch:

```
sudo adafruit-pitft-helper -t 35r
```

Another change that I made is to remove the adafruit duplicate in `/boot/config.txt`, and now after rebooting the only thing I get is a big white screen.

**Update:** this what I removed

```
# --- added by adafruit-pitft-helper Fri Aug  7 16:06:03 UTC 2015 ---
[pi1] 
device_tree=bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb 
[pi2]   device_tree=bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb [all]
 dtparam=spi=on
 dtparam=i2c1=on
 dtparam=i2c_arm=on
 dtoverlay=pitft28r,rotate=90,speed=32000000,fps=20
# --- end adafruit-pitft-helper Fri Aug  7 16:06:03 UTC 2015 ---
```

I got 2 section like described with just the difference in one line

```
 dtoverlay=pitft28r,rotate=90,speed=32000000,fps=20
 dtoverlay=pitft35r,rotate=90,speed=42000000,fps=20
```

So I removed the first section !!!

I have ran all commands again either for 2.8, or 3.5 but that hasn't changed anything.

Any suggestions will be appreciated :) thanks

Comment: What did you remove out of `/boot/config.txt`?

Comment: @Wilf please see the updated post

Comment: it worked when using it with a new sd card because  installing raspberrypi-bootloader and adafruit-pitft-helper makes a lot of changes in the system ...

Comment: It may be that the 3.5" requires some of the stuff provided for the 2.8". It may work to use a version of boot config not modifed by `adafruit-pitft-helper`, and then use the command `sudo adafruit-pitft-helper -t 35r` and it might set it up as needed (though the thing seems to be for 2.4" & 2.8")- you could use [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/easy-install)  (which is for [this](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2097)), but I would suggest contacting them in case the wrong software/firmware/drivers/stuff blows things up.

Comment: @Wilf i will contact them because they don't tell what changes are made (because not just the config file how is changed)